# How to install Tailwind CSS in html correctly?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I just want to know that how to install Tailwind CSS properly
all I want the steps 1 by 1 because I have tried to do so but it doesn't work properly

I have tried to copy the steps from the main website of twilwind.com but I don't get the right installation I don't know why somehow

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks? Such as NextJS, Vue, or plain NodeJS? Or are you only using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want to use node/npm or not ? Tailwindcss does not have a default css file you can copy anymore, you will need to actually run tailwindcss to generate the css file. You can follow this article : https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli if you don't want to have node/npm installed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have node.js and npm installed I will give you the cdn approch.

[Here is the official documentation link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) This is where I answered from

Add this below script inside your `head` tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

And you should be able to play with tailwind in built classes

if you want to customize tailwind configuration
add another script tag below the previous one
ex:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>    
 <script>
        tailwind.config = {
          theme: {
            extend: {
              colors: {
                clifford: '#da373d',
              }
            }
          }
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: i do not want to install through "cdn" but i want to install it from "npm" because i have tried many times but every time a problem occurs

Comment: If you want to do it through npm, Moussa Bistami's answer should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on `<head>` and in html you must add the `<script>`

```
<head>
     <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
     <script>
        tailwind.config = {
          theme: {
            extend: {
              colors: {
                clifford: '#da373d',
              }
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: I would mention that this is for development purposes only.